# Unable to log in to ubuntu 16.04 after installing wifi adapter driver

Tags: 16.04, login

I installed WiFi driver for my TP-Link adapter by using [rtl8192cu-fixes](https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes).
After reboot, suddenly I am unable to log in into my ubuntu However, I can log in by using terminal.

1. I run the recovery mode using `dpkg` but it doesn’t work.
2. run `chown username:username .Xauthority`

Comment: Hello and welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please add more details on how you installed the `rtl8192cu-fixes`. From you question is is impossible to guess, what broke your system.

Comment: Unable to login to Ubuntu however you can login using terminal?  Do you mean you can't login via gui.  Gui logins require the creation of work files in $HOME (your user directory) where as text logins do not, so I'd firstly check you have some space in your user directory ($HOME). If it's full (or very near full) you need to use your text login to create some space so a gui login can proceed.  Your question is rather unclear, so please clarify.

Comment: the steps are from https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes  

git clone https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes.git<br/>
sudo dkms add ./rtl8192cu-fixes<br/>
sudo dkms install 8192cu/1.11<br/>
sudo depmod -a<br/>